# How can I efficiently see the contents of a renamed file maintained under git?

Tags: git, rename, git-log

With the *git* command

```
git log --follow --pretty='format %H %ae %ai' foo.c
```

I get a list of changes that affected the file `foo.c`. Then, given a hash *H* from the *git log* output, I can run

```
git show H:foo.c
```

to see the file's contents at that point of time.

This doesn't work if the file has been renamed; *git* complains:

```
fatal: Path 'foo.c' exists on disk, but not in '34cd81d75f398ee455e61969b118639dacbfd7a6'.
```

What is the most efficient way obtain the renamed file's contents?

Comment: You need to show the file by the name it had at that time.  How do you get that name?  Well, this is far from perfect but might be a good step getting there: `git log --follow --pretty='format:%H' builtin/var.c | while read hash; do git diff-tree -M -r --diff-filter=R $hash; done` (applied to git source tree, finds builtin/var.c came from var.c and builtin-var.c).  But it's quite verbose as it finds other renames in those commits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized, you can add the `--diff-filter=R` to the `git log --follow` command.  (I've edited this into the answer.)  This cuts down the number of hashes to inspect, to just those that rename the file in question.  However, one still must extract the file-rename separately.

---

Here's the above comment turned into a script ... no claims about how pretty it is or is not. :-)  It needs more work to be turned into a real command.

```
#! /bin/sh

# Find git commits that rename the given path.
identify()
{
    local path="$1"
    local IFS=$'\t'

    # 1) log with follow to extract hashes that rename the file
    #
    # 2) diff-tree each hash to get the actual rename involved
    #
    # 3) extract the hash and :<...>R line with old/new paths
    git log --follow --pretty='format:%H' --diff-filter=R -- "$path" |
    while read hash; do
        echo $hash
        git diff-tree -M -r --diff-filter=R $hash
    done |
    while read line; do
        case "$line" in
        :*)
            set -- $line
            # $2 is oldname, $3 is new name
            # we already have the new name, we need to back
            # up to the old one.
            [ "$3" != "$path" ] && continue
            # at and before this commit, use $2, the old name
            echo at and before $hash use $2
            path=$2;;
        *)
            hash=$line;;
        esac
    done
}

identify builtin/var.c
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was hoping to void a second expensive loop after _git log_, which also takes considerable resources.  It seems there is no efficient way to do that.  The _git log_ command knows the renaming, but doesn't offer a way to use it directly.

Comment: `git log` actually gets it right out of the diffcore machinery.  Unfortunately, this requires traversing all the diffs with rename detection turned on, so it's kind of expensive no matter what, and hence not the default; but it might be nice if `git log --follow` could be convinced to sneak the information through some side channel, perhaps.  Otherwise, as you note (and I coded) you have to repeat all that expensive work!